# Tracking Scans Occurring Outside Flutter App with QrImage in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tracking, scanning

I'm utilizing the QrImage widget in Flutter to generate QR codes containing vCard data. When scanned, these QR codes prompt the user to add contacts to their phone. However, I'm seeking a method to track or log these scans when they occur outside of the app environment.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
QrImage(
  data: data,
  version: QrVersions.auto,
  size: Get.height * 0.3,
  embeddedImage: const AssetImage(
    'assets/images/no-profile.png',
  ),
  embeddedImageStyle: QrEmbeddedImageStyle(
    size: const Size(
      20,
      20,
    ),
  ),
),
```

The QR code's 'data' variable contains vCard information. When a user scans this QR code, it directs them to add a contact in their phone's contacts.

Is there a way, using Flutter or any external method, to track or log these scans when they occur outside of the app, perhaps when the user adds the contact? Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to achieve this tracking functionality would be greatly appreciated.